# Zoom not working in wxpython Toolbar widget

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython, toolbar, figure

The zoom button does not update the display once you zoom in. It only shows the boxes that you make when trying to zoom into an area but it doesn't update it once you let go of the mouse button. It does update when you click on of the other buttons though. Also, the toolbar keeps disappearing when I use the zoom button. Working on a mac right now. The code is from [this example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_wx2.html) but I will also paste it below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
An example of how to use wx or wxagg in an application with the new
toolbar - comment out the setA_toolbar line for no toolbar
"""

# Used to guarantee to use at least Wx2.8
import wxversion
wxversion.ensureMinimal('2.8')

from numpy import arange, sin, pi

import matplotlib

# uncomment the following to use wx rather than wxagg
#matplotlib.use('WX')
#from matplotlib.backends.backend_wx import FigureCanvasWx as FigureCanvas

# comment out the following to use wx rather than wxagg
matplotlib.use('WXAgg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas

from matplotlib.backends.backend_wx import NavigationToolbar2Wx

from matplotlib.figure import Figure

import wx

class CanvasFrame(wx.Frame):
     def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,None,-1,
                         'CanvasFrame',size=(550,350))

        self.SetBackgroundColour(wx.NamedColour("WHITE"))

        self.figure = Figure()
        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        t = arange(0.0,3.0,0.01)
        s = sin(2*pi*t)

        self.axes.plot(t,s)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figure)

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.LEFT | wx.TOP | wx.GROW)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.Fit()

        self.add_toolbar()  # comment this out for no toolbar


    def add_toolbar(self):
        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Wx(self.canvas)
        self.toolbar.Realize()
        if wx.Platform == '__WXMAC__':
            # Mac platform (OSX 10.3, MacPython) does not seem to cope with
            # having a toolbar in a sizer. This work-around gets the buttons
            # back, but at the expense of having the toolbar at the top
            self.SetToolBar(self.toolbar)
        else:
            # On Windows platform, default window size is incorrect, so set
            # toolbar width to figure width.
            tw, th = self.toolbar.GetSizeTuple()
            fw, fh = self.canvas.GetSizeTuple()
            # By adding toolbar in sizer, we are able to put it at the bottom
            # of the frame - so appearance is closer to GTK version.
            # As noted above, doesn't work for Mac.
            self.toolbar.SetSize(wx.Size(fw, th))
            self.sizer.Add(self.toolbar, 0, wx.LEFT | wx.EXPAND)
        # update the axes menu on the toolbar
        self.toolbar.update()


    def OnPaint(self, event):
        self.canvas.draw()

class App(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        'Create the main window and insert the custom frame'
        frame = CanvasFrame()
        frame.Show(True)

    return True

app = App(0)
app.MainLoop()
```